# AngularJS ng-repeat for firebase json output

Tags: json, angularjs

I'm using firebase to get the json data and a typical json output looks like:

```
$scope.data = {
"val1":{"name":"xyz","gender":"male"},
"val2":{"name":"asd","gender":"male"},
"val3":{"name":"qwe","gender":"female"}
}
```

I have tried

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">{{value.name}}</li>
```

But still not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: wokring fine : http://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/2j6cesvz/

Comment: the above code should work... do you see any error in console ?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I forgot to add $scope.$apply();   once I fetched the data. Now it is solved!!